# How can I create Collapsible Column header in Data Table?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, datatable

I have this Below Code. What I want is I want to make HR Information column and contact column to be collapsible by adding + and - symbol next to them name. How can I do it?

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css"
   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%"  >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
         <th colspan="2" class="header-1"  name="speed">HR Information <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" /></th>
         <th colspan="4">Contact</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="this_h">
         <th id="hrcolumn" class="x"  name="speed">Position</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td>$320,800</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>5421</td>
         <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>$170,750</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>8422</td>
         <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td>$86,000</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>1562</td>
         <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: "300px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        fixedColumns: true
    });
});
th, td {
    white - space: nowrap;
    padding - left: 40 px!important;
    padding - right: 40 px!important;
}
div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 800 px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think putting the icon next to the column name is the best idea, as when you hide the columns, the icon itself would be hidden.

Instead of this I have added two checkboxes above the table that will be of better use.

```
<p>Toggle HR Info <input id="hrCheck" type="checkbox" /></p>
<p>Toggle Contact Info <input id="contactCheck" type="checkbox" /></p>
```

I had to fix the colspan for the Contact column as it needed to be 3 instead of 4.

Here is a working jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kaloxokadu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you Jake! I like your idea. But is it possible to  putting the icon next to the name and just show only first  detail level column  on and hide others  when click on icon? I really appreciate with your help..

Comment: I have updated the previous post try this: https://jsbin.com/jejaxowede/edit?html,js

If this is correct please don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jake! I have  many numbers of columns in parent header.In here, i am just showing few columns to make this easy. I have  many numbers of columns in parent header so i want to make header toggle or collapsible so users don't have to scroll all the way right or left. I will try to make  changes in your code and make this work. If not make it then i will  mark  your last comment as answer. Really appreciate your help!